# How to get wp offload media lite to think it offloaded a piece of media when it did not

Tags: php, wordpress

This is for a custom upload process where a large file is chunked to Google Cloud Storage from the client side using a signed url. After the file has completed uploading, I make an ajax request to add the attachment post to the WP database. This all works except for integrating with WP Offload Media Lite, as when adding the attachment post to the database the plugin does not think it offloaded the media. This is despite GCS being the provider defined in the plugin's settings area. I need to find a way to make the plugin "think" it uploaded a piece of media when it didn't. I've looked at the deliciousbrains docs and codebase and it does not appear there's a straight-forward way to approach this. Any ideas helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what an answer to this question would even look like. Concerning the internals of Wordpress, I believe it's open source, so you can use a debugger to find out where it makes the decision that your request is not valid. From there, explore the code around if there are any customization points.

Comment: Add some codes, app and environment info and more details of the problem...

Comment: Maybe a filter in the plugin that fires "after offload" or something. Hard to tell. You could ask Delicious Brains support team too

Answer (score 0):

[WP Offload Media Lite upload existing files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71191873/wp-offload-media-lite-upload-existing-files?rq=2) this post was a huge help. Also using the as3cf global's get_core_setting method too.